# Google chart needs to refresh the page to display

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, charts

I'm actually occuring an error with google chart. I looked on other subject but none gave me a solution.

I have a "dashboard" with 9 tiles which each contains a chart. Wehn i go on that page, it randomly display some chart or no one. Then if i refresh, it loads normally.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

This is my includ in the header of my page. Then i have my differents function includes. ( I put 1 for example):

```
function successA1(data, no_tile, color){
var tile_data = data.tile_data;

function A1() {

    var dataGoogle = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(tile_data);

    var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        colors: [color], //!*DEV*!/
        curveType: 'function',
        fontSize: 12,
        tooltip: {
            trigger: 'both'
        },
        chartArea: {
            top: 15,
            left: 60,
            height: 160,
            width: 290,
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart' + no_tile));

    chart.draw(dataGoogle, options);
    $(document).find('#chart' + no_tile).closest('div.A1').addClass('ready');
}// end of A1

$(document).find('#chart' + no_tile).closest('.A1').find('.tileSummury').text(data.tile_data[13][1] + ' trained participants');

     google.setOnLoadCallback(A1);
    } // end of successA1
```

Then i have all my html which contains my differents ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: {key: ApiKey, course_id: course_id},
        error: function (data) {
            swal('Error', 'The distant server cannot be reached', 'error')
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                successA1(data, '{{ $tiles[$i]->no_tile }}', '{{ $tiles[$i]->color }}');
            });
        }
    });
```

And then I have my include of th library

```
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages': ['corechart', 'gauge']});
```

The ajax request are triggered before the plugin load but the usage of the function that draw my chart are done after a document.ready

If someone has an idea. And btw I'm on laravel 4.2.

Thanks

Comment: use set time out and load another charts after first one loaded...

Comment: I can't I have 20 kind of tiles and th order can change from one user to other.